# Read binary file and convert to ASCII in Python

Tags: python, binary

I'm working on proprietary software as a side project at work, so I'm unable to share source files. However, I can share my current starting code and its output.

My code:

```
import os, sys
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
sys.path.append(parentdir)
#
testfile = os.path.join(currentdir, 'vlctge55.mb1')
testhand = open(testfile, 'rb')
with open(os.path.join(currentdir, 'test01output.txt'),'w') as fhand:
    lines = testhand.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        fhand.write(f'{line}\n')
```

This gives me the following output. I'm trying to figure out the best way to go through the output and convert the \x00-formatted strings to their ASCII counterparts, unless I'm fundamentally missing something here. In between massive chunks of these \x00-formatted snippets, there is regular text as well. I've tried `b'\x00'.decode('ascii')` and `b'\x00'.decode('utf-8')` but for whatever reason it's just not giving me good output. I keep getting `'\x00'` back as output. What am I missing?

```
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xf1\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xeeh\x00\x00\x00\x02vlctge55v\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00BAC8\x006734\x00\x00#\x83\xa1
```

Comment: First things first, don't read binary data with `readlines()`. Second, you can't decode binary data to `ascii`. Its not Ascii, its not text at all, its binary. What output do you specifically want?

Comment: I'm looking for any sort of output that's even vaguely human-legible. Within the file's output, there is regular ASCII text that I'm expecting to see, from looking over auto-generated reports that are created with these .mb1 files. However, I'm really looking for something human-legible or at least something I can parse through to continue processing these files.

Comment: Are you trying to re-implement [strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strings_(Unix))?

Comment: `I'm really looking for something human-legible` The hexadecimal output you're seeing is the closest you can get to 'human-legible' output for binary data.

Comment: @tkausl That's what I was afraid of. I'm attempting to build my own version of software we currently use, but it's written in .NET and I don't have the source code, so it's a bit difficult to see how they're processing these .mb1 files.

Comment: You could open the file in binary mode (as you currently do) then read one byte at a time. Check to see if a byte is potentially printable (decimal range 32-126 inclusive) then print it. Whether the output from that is going to make any sense is another matter altogether